# android studio error: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-24'

Tags: android, android-studio

I just downloaded android studio and it wouldn't download I keep getting

> Error: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-24'.

please help me, if you have an idea because I cannot do anything and its annoying.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: click on `install missing platforms` and proceed

Answer (score 1):

click 'install missing platforms'
or
modify the build.gradle file and change buildToolsVersion to whatever version you have.

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle file change build tools version to the latest SDK version numbers.